# Turning two switched outlets into a half switched outlet when only 2 wire is used.

Tags: electrical

I have power coming into a switch and then proceeding on to two outlets. Only 2 wire is used. Am I able to half switch one of the outlets if there is only 2 wire available?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. Pulling is not an option due to corner and 4 studs. Maybe ill look for additional source in crawlspace.

Answer (score 2):

No you won't be able to do this without a third wire since you need to be able to supply an unswitched hot to the outlet in addition to the switched .  You might want to look into some wireless remote options if pulling a new cable is out of the question.